# Freeing struct with unclosed file in C

Tags: c, file, struct, memory-leaks, free

I don't have much experience in C, my question is as follows:

if I have a struct like this:

```c
typedef struct {
  FILE* file;
  ...
  ...
} MyStruct;
```

and a function to free this struct:

```c
void free_mystruct(MyStruct* s) {
  if (!s) {
    return;
  }

  if (!s->file) {
    free(s);
    s = NULL;
    return;
  }

  if (fclose(s->file) != 0) {
    // it failed to close the file...
    // how to handle the free?
  }

  free(s);
  s = NULL;
}
```

does freeing the struct anyways inside the `if`   block where it fails to close the file leak memory or system resources? if it does how to handle the free in a situation like this should I report that it failed and don't perform the `free()` call and return?

I think this question comes down to the situations where  `fclose()` fails, probably. I don't know these.

EDIT:
this is how `MyStruct` is initialized:

```c
MyStruct* mystruct_new(const char* filename) {
  MyStruct* ms = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
  if (!ms) {
    return NULL;
  }

  FILE* file = fopen(filename, "w+");
  if (!file) {
    free(ms);
    ms = NULL;
    return NULL;
  }

  ms->file = file;
  return ms;
}
```

`main` can look like this:

```c
int main(void) {
  MyStruct* ms = mystruct_new("file.txt");
  if (!ms) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // do something with `ms`...

  free_mystruct(ms);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: There is very little you can do if `fclose` fails. The best course of action is to print an error message and possibly exit the program.

Comment: I will add more details to the question on how I initialize `MyStruct`

Comment: @h0r53 There is nothing wrong whatsoever with `free_mystruct` except extraneous `s = NULL` --- one never needs that. `free(s->file)` would be a grave error --- you never, ever `free` a `FILE*`.

Comment: @EpsilonCode after looking it over, I'm sure you're using `fopen` to create the `file` portion of `MyStruct`. If that's the case, then you just use `fclose` to free up resources created by `fopen`. If `fclose` fails, that is unrelated to freeing the `MyStruct` object assuming you dynamically allocated it.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit I would argue that `s = NULL` is a good thing. Otherwise, "use-after-free" bugs are possible.

Comment: i added more details to the question

Comment: @EpsilonCode thanks for the update. As expected, you are initializing a MyStruct variable with `malloc(sizeof(MyStruct))`. Thus, the `free_mystruct` code looks good as it is. It should safely free the structure created by `mystruct_new`. There isn't much you can do about `fclose()` failing and in some cases you shouldn't worry about it because you are done with the file. It can fail for a variety of reasons, but your code as-is would not have memory leaks if `fclose` failed.

Comment: @h0r53 The effects of `s = NULL` are not seen outside of `free_mystruct`, so it's pointless there. Inside `free_mystruct` `free(s);` should be the very last statement, no use after free is possible, so it's pointless there too.

Comment: "The effects of s = NULL are not seen outside of free_mystruct" - oh but they are. `s` is passed as a pointer. It's scope is beyond that of the `free_mystruct` function. Yes we don't have enough information in this example, but that doesn't mean there isn't potential for the caller of `free_mystruct` to keep using the pointer after freeing it.

Comment: @h0r53 Thanks for your answer, you might as well add it as an answer.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit I would also say that the `= NULL` part is a good thing, because when it comes to what i know, freeing the memory will not make the pointer pointing to it a `falsy` value, a check like `if (ptr != NULL) { ... }` which **might** be used to guard against free-ed memory would actually not work here.

Comment: 99.9% of people just assume that fclose can't fail. Because of exactly this reason - what are you supposed to do if you can't close the file? The problem is not just "how do I free(s)", it's actually "what the heck do I do now?" I guarantee you that if this did happen, 99% of programs would just not close the file, and free the struct anyway, and keep going the same as if they did close the file.\

Comment: `s` *goes out of scope* at the next statement. It disappears forever without a trace. No `if (s != NULL)` is possible after that point.

Comment: How is `s` going out of scope? It's passed in as a pointer, meaning the *value* of `s` is not stored as a local stack variable; it's scope is beyond that of this function.

Comment: @user253751 If the file is open for writing, you can call `fflush()` prior to closing it.  That's the most likely cause of failure on `fclose()`.  At least if `fflush()` fails you know what went wrong, and you can probably call `fclose()` without failure.

Comment: @h0r53 Scope is for *names*. The *name* goes out of scope. "it's scope is beyond that of this function." This is an outright falsehood.

Comment: The name `s` "goes out of scope" yes. Whatever address it stored doesn't, and any other external variables storing that address do not either. The main takeaway is the `free_mystruct` method accepts the MyStruct pointer by value, and as such the local version is indeed "locally scoped." The address of that variable is not the same address as the variable used for passing the pointer by value. So `s = NULL` is indeed redundant. In some situations, you may want to keep that data off the stack when the function returns, but that discussion is well beyond the original discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, you are initializing a `MyStruct` variable with `malloc(sizeof(MyStruct))`. Thus, the `free_mystruct` code looks good as it is. It should safely free the structure created by `mystruct_new`.

It will first check to see if the argument `MyStruct* s` is `null`, if not then it will attempt to close the `FILE*` variable with `fclose` (if it exists), and finally it will `free(s)` which is the appropriate way to deallocate the memory created with `malloc(sizeof(MyStruct))`. It also sets the argument `MyStruct* s` to `null`, <s>which helps avoid dangerous use-after-free bugs that could appear in other parts of your code</s>.

**Regarding fclose failing**

In some cases you won't need to worry about `fclose` failing because you are done with the file. `fclose` can fail for a variety of reasons, but your code as-is would not have memory leaks if `fclose` failed. This question is about creating and destroying instances of `MyStruct`, and the methods you've provided for doing so are *reasonably safe* (bugs are possible in code that uses this structure, but are not in the code you've provided).

---

**UPDATE: Regarding 's = NULL'**

In the comments there has been discussion regarding the utility of `s = NULL` as well as the potential of bugs such as 'use-after-free'.

Before getting into examples, it should be noted that in `free_mystruct` we are passing a `MyStruct` pointer by value. That means a new variable is created local to the function which stores the value of the pointer that was passed in. Changing the value of the local pointer does not change the value of the external one - however, changes to the address being pointed to will (which is why `free(s)` works).

Here is a simple example:

```
int main(void) {
  MyStruct* ms = mystruct_new("file.txt");
  if (!ms) {
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("The variable `ms` points to: %p\n", ms);
  printf("A few bytes at `ms`: %x\n", *ms);

  free_mystruct(ms);

  printf("The variable `ms` points to: %p\n", ms);
  printf("A few bytes at `ms`: %x\n", *ms);

  return 0;
}
```

When I run the above, I receive output such as the following:

```
The variable `ms` points to: 0x1516069f0
A few bytes at `ms`:         fca465a0
The variable `ms` points to: 0x1516069f0
A few bytes at `ms`:                0
```

This is what we should expect. The address of the pointer variable doesn't change, and therefore `s = NULL` does not take affect on that variable (outside of the `free_mystruct`) function. However, the data at `ms` appears to have been freed.

If you're following along this far, you should see that potential for a 'use-after-free' bug does still exist. It wasn't enough to nullify the pointer that was passed by value. It would be safer if the code did something like this:

```
free_mystruct(ms);
ms = 0;
```

Notice how the above sets the pointer to 0, but it is now the burden of the caller to do this (or ensure that the free'd MyStruct isn't referenced elsewhere in the code).

These types of nuances are common in C, where memory management is ultimately up to the developer. The code that the OP provided isn't buggy itself, but the developer using it should be aware of potential misuses that could result in security bugs.

---

**DIGGING EVEN DEEPER**

If we look another layer deeper we can see that `free` only nullifies the first byte of a dynamically allocated address range. That is why the output from earlier implied that the data at `ms` was null bytes after the free. In the following example, we can see that is not actually the case.

```
int main(void) {
  // STEP 1: Memory at MyStruct before malloc
  puts("STEP 1");
  MyStruct* ms;
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(MyStruct); i++)
    printf(" %02hhx", ms[i]);
  puts("\n");

  // STEP 2: Memory at MyStruct after malloc
  puts("STEP 2");
  ms = mystruct_new("file.txt");
  if (!ms) {
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("The variable `ms` points to: %p\n", ms);
  printf("A few bytes at `ms`");
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(MyStruct); i++)
    printf(" %02hhx", ms[i]);
  puts("\n");

  // STEP 3: Memory at MyStruct after free
  puts("STEP 3");
  free_mystruct(ms);
  printf("The variable `ms` points to: %p\n", ms);
  printf("A few bytes at `ms`");
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(MyStruct); i++)
    printf(" %02hhx", ms[i]);
  puts("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
STEP 1
 88 00 80 00 01 01 00 80

STEP 2
The variable `ms` points to: 0x14ce069f0
A few bytes at `ms` a0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00

STEP 3
The variable `ms` points to: 0x14ce069f0
A few bytes at `ms` 00 00 60 00 03 00 00 00
```

The main takeaway here is that **free(...) does not nullify all of the bytes in the memory that was de-allocated**. That means that the data stored at a dynamically allocated location may remain in memory after `free(...)` is called.

This is yet another reason why not setting `ms = NULL` after deallocating the structure could be dangerous.

Comment: "which helps avoid dangerous use-after-free bugs that could appear in other parts of your code" PSA: it doesn't do any such thing. `s = NULL` is *utterly pointless* in this particular function. If you think it helps avoid some kind of bug, you can try and come up with a program that would exhibit such a bug outside of `free_mystruct`, and show how `s = NULL` inside `free_mystruct` helps prevent it.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit thank you for the input and I've updated the answer with more details as  well as an example